# align each month with right days of the week?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, momentjs, ejs

I'm creating a calendar app and right now I'm trying to make my days dynamic.

so far in the backend, I have an array which gives me the number of days in each month.

```
const DaysInEachMonth = [
  moment('2017-01').daysInMonth(),
  moment('2017-02').daysInMonth(),
  moment('2017-03').daysInMonth(),
  moment('2017-04').daysInMonth(),
  moment('2017-05').daysInMonth(),
  moment('2017-06').daysInMonth(),
  moment('2017-07').daysInMonth(),
  moment('2017-08').daysInMonth(),
  moment('2017-09').daysInMonth(),
  moment('2017-10').daysInMonth(),
  moment('2017-11').daysInMonth(),
  moment('2017-12').daysInMonth()
];
```

In my ejs file I'm using DaysInEachMonth to loop through the number of days.

```
<ul id="days">
<% for(var i = 0; i <= 11; i++) { %>
    <% var n = DaysInEachMonth[i] %>
    <% for(var j=1; j <= n; j++) { %>
      <li> <%= j %> </li>
      <% } %> 
<% } %>
</ul>
```

Now the problem I'm having is that all days in each month display under January. How do I make it so every time I press the next button to go the next month my days change as well. Maybe this is not the best way of doing it. Any help would be great as you can see I'm new to Node.

Comment: It is really hard to help you because what you are doing is not something I would personally do at all. So technically, you need to show us working code using CodePen, or something similar. I would personally create a view that represents a single month, and render a new view every time you slide to the sides, then append it to the invisible area - one month ahead at a time. In other words - Pre-load a month at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to agree with @Alexus; this is not something I would personally do.

But to answer your question, `moment.js` has powerful ways to manipulate dates.

For example, `moment#month(number|String)` can change the month. And by using that, you can do things like I did in the following snippet:

```js
// Let's just set `nthMonth` to the 10th month for this example.
var nthMonth = 10;
// This gets the month November. (the tenth month when starting from 0)
var month = moment().month(nthMonth);
// This gets the amount of days in November
var daysInMonth = month.daysInMonth();
// Using the moment#format function, we can get a human-readable string from the date.
// By using the format 'MMMM', we only get the name of the month.
var monthName = month.format('MMMM')

console.log('Moment.JS Example:');
console.log('    Nth month:', nthMonth)
console.log('Name of month:', monthName)
console.log('Days in month:', daysInMonth)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

This is also applicable to your code. EJS is not supported in StackOverflow snippets, but I think you can see how it works:

```js
// And just for your code:
var m = moment();
var days = $('#days');
for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
  m.month(i);
  days.append(`<li class="month">${m.format('MMMM')}</li>`);

  var n = m.daysInMonth();
  for (var j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
    // We could use this code to show only the numbers.
    //days.append(`<li>${j}</li>`);
    // Or we use this code to make it a bit fancier.
    days.append(`<li>${m.date(j).format('dddd Do')}</li>`);
  }
}
```

```css
#days > li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.month {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: .5em
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="days">
</ul>
```